# Pull img element(?) from string of JSON

Tags: vb.net

I'm going to create an XKCD viewer in Visual Basic .NET, but I have no experience with JSON or any web development syntax for that matter.

I've found this URL on XKCD's 'About' page, which pulls the daily comic.

http://xkcd.com/info.0.json

Obviously, I can see that "img":"" is where I need to pull the image contents. But I'm unsure as to the conventionally 'correct' method of parsing JSON. Should I just convert the page contents to a string and parse the URL out of it that way or is there a more accepted way of doing this kind of thing?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [JavascriptSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx) class to parse the JSON string and extract whatever you wish from the properties of the resulting object.

Comment: This should work fine but `JavascriptSerializer` is pretty slow compared to 3rd party libraries like [Json.NET](https://json.codeplex.com/).